# Отключить индексацию папки "Загрузки"

Tags: windows, windows-10

Как отключить индексацию папки "Загрузки" в Windows 10? WSearch уже давно отключена, не помогает.

Comment: Версия ОС? Как вы определяете при отключенном Search, что индексация всё же есть?

Comment: Windows 10 Домашняя.

Comment: Очень просто - при нажатии на папку "Загрузки" начинается индексация папки, во время которой содержимое папки недоступно, это может продолжаться очень долго в зависимости от размера содержимого папки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не индексирование, как таковое. Как правило, при открытии папки "Загрузки" Windows 10 обрабатывает ее, как папку с изображениями, и пытается создавать эскизы для каждого файла. Это долго. Если хотите ускорить открытие папки, уберите этот режим, для этого - правый клик по папке, выберите "Свойства", далее вкладку "Настройки", и под надписью "Оптимизировать эту папку" выберите в выпадающем меню вариант "Общие элементы", а также установите флажок "Применить этот же шаблон ко всем подпапкам", как на скриншоте:

[[image: Свойства папки "Загрузки"[1]]

Ну, и нажмите кнопку "Применить". После этого она будет загружаться значительно быстрее.
Если же и это не сильно поможет, значит, пора чистить папку :)

Comment: Спасибо, Виктор, значительно помогло!

Comment: Рано обрадовался, проблема осталась прежней. Размер паки "Загрузки" - 59 гб, которые содержатся в 431 файле.

Comment: @AnvarF Скрытых папок/файлов нет?

Comment: В свойствах папки отмечено "отображать скрытые файлы". На первый взгляд нет, но возможно в каких-то вложенных папках могут быть и скрытые.